# Doctrine HasLifecycleCallback not calling PrePersist (or anything)

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am actually getting a

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column &#039;created_at&#039; cannot be null
```

error, because the PrePersist is not being executed.  I have searched around and the biggest gotchas seemed to be making sure @HasLifecycleCallback in the class annotations and the @PrePersist in the function being used.

I'm lost, why is my code not calling the PrePersist?

here's the entity file

```
<?php
namespace RaffleTools\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 *
 * @Entity
 * @HasLifecycleCallbacks
 * @Table(name="raffleitems")
 **/
class RaffleItem
{
    /**
     * @var int
     * @Id @Column(type="integer") @GeneratedValue
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $image;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     * @Column(name="created_at", type="datetime")
     */
    protected $createdAt;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     * @Column(name="updated_at", type="datetime")
     */
    protected $updatedAt;

    /**
     * @PrePersist
     * @PreUpdate
     */
    public function updatedTimestamps()
    {
        $this->setUpdatedAt(new \DateTime('now'));

        if ($this->getCreatedAt() == null) {
            $this->setCreatedAt(new \DateTime('now'));
        }
    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function getImage()
    {
        return $this->image;
    }

    public function setImage($image)
    {
        $this->image = $image;
    }

    public function setCreatedAt(\DateTime $createdAt)
    {
        $this->createdAt = $createdAt;
    }

    public function getCreatedAt()
    {
        return $this->createdAt;
    }

    public function setUpdatedAt(\DateTime $updatedAt)
    {
        $this->updatedAt = $updatedAt;
    }

    public function getUpdatedAt()
    {
        return $this->updatedAt;
    }

    public function toArray()
    {
        return get_object_vars($this);
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I just came back to this today, and low and behold it works...

Comment: is there some kind of caching going on somewhere that I am not aware of?

Answer (score 0):

Sadly this was a typo in the config setup

```
$env = $injector->make(Env::class);
$paths = array(__DIR__.'/../');
$isDevMode = isset($enf['DEVELOPMENT']);

// the connection configuration
$dbParams = array(
    'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
    'host' => $env['DB_HOST'],
    'user' => $env['DB_USER'],
    'password' => $env['DB_PASS'],
    'dbname' => $env['DB_NAME'],
);

$config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration($paths, $isDevMode);
```

in the line that says `$isDevMode = isset($enf['DEVELOPMENT']);` $env is spelled wrong and returned false all the time.